# Book in a free body diagram

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, free-body-diagram

If a book is laying on a table and the gravity is bigger than the tables force. What direction will the book go to?

Comment: Have you tried to walk on water?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are no other forces and the table is not  moving, the book would go through the table (presumably breaking the table), since the net force on it is downwards.